# Python: find and download missing files from google drive (using a sharable link)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Given a sharable link to a google drive folder (folder ID), I would like to compare the dir list under this folder with the dir list under a given path, and download the missing files.

I've read about `PyDrive` but couldn't find an elegant way to access the drive folder without authentication.

For instance:

```
files_under_gdrive = ["File1", "File2", "File3"]
files_under_given_path = ["File1", "some_other_file"]

# Download missing files found only in Google Drive
...

files_under_given_path = ["File1", "some_other_file", "File2", "File3"]
```

Any hint/idea would be highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: So basically you want to retrieve the files from these two folders *without authentication*?

Comment: @ale13 maybe I wasn't clear- the second folder ("files_under_given_path") is local, so no authentication needed. 
To access the folder in Google Drive I have a folder ID, generated from a sharable link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily start by gathering the files from the local directory and store their names in a list for example.

Afterwards, in order to retrieve the files from the Google Drive Shared drive, you can make use of `Files.list` request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

With the `includeItemsFromAllDrives` set to `true` and the `driveId` field set to the corresponding id of the shared drive. Depending on your exact needs and requirements, you may add other fields to the request as well.

After retrieving the files from the shared Google Drive, you can simply compare the two lists and based on the results, download the needed files. For downloading the files, you may want to check this snippet from the [Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#python):

```
file_id = 'ID_OF_THE_FILE_TO_DOWNLOAD'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

*However, I recommend you to start by completing the Google Drive Quick Start with Python from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python).*

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list);
- [Drive API v3 download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#python);
- [Drive API v3 Python Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python).